# How can I monitor entire computer for any file change?

Tags: c#, file, find, monitor, filesystemwatcher

I want to monitor my entire computer files for any change. Such as, file creations, deletions, modifications, attribute changes, etc. I know that there is a control called filesystemwatcher but that's pretty much all I know. I want to make this application in hopes of finding viruses on the computer whenever I get one. your help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Umm, do you have any idea how many files change on your computer at any given moment?  Even if you can monitor *everything*, you'd have to wade through logs of lots of legitimate writes to find anything suspicious.  There are virus scanner applications that do real time monitoring (including a lot more than just file system monitoring).  My recommentation is to not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman actually not that much to be impossible to monitor.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp I didn't say it was impossible, just that its a big task and there are alternatives.

Comment: thanks I guess I'll look into it but I guess I won't be trying anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with virus is that their activity is hard to distinguish from legitimate use. Also, FileSystemWatcher is asynchronous, i.e. you can be notified but you can't prevent the operation.

To prevent the operation from happening you need to use a filesystem filter driver, as all antiviruses do. You can write your own (at least 6 man-months of work) or use our CallbackFilter product for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at FileWatcher Class here are a couple of links

[How to implement a simple filewatcher Windows service in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18521/How-to-implement-a-simple-filewatcher-Windows-serv)

[MSDN FileSystemWatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)